# Does socket.io handle keepalives automatically?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, keep-alive, linode

I am using node.js and socket.io on a Linode server. I was told that I should use KeepAlives with my app in order to make use of a Linode NodeBalancer. I was also told that I had to set the NodeBalancer protocol to use TCP rather than (HTTP or HTTPS which both disable KeepAlives).

My question is, are KeepAlives already implemented in socket.io by default? There seems to be something keeping the connection alive so I am thinking that this is already handled by socket.io. However, I cannot seem to find any info on this topic. If KeepAlives are not implemented by default in socket.io what problems will I face using the NodeBalancer? If I should be implementing KeepAlives what steps do I need to take to implement them in my app?

As an additional question, if KeepAlives are implemented in socket.io, what issues will I face if I use the HTTP option rather than TCP?

Comment: What do you mean the HTTP option?  Do you mean socket.io http polling?  Eeeck, why in the world would you do that?  Polling is substantially less efficient than a webSocket connection.  FYI, both HTTP and socket.io use TCP underneath so I'm not sure why you're calling one option TCP.  And, just for completeness a socket.io connection starts with an HTTP request too.

Comment: @jfriend00 By HTTP option I mean the HTTP option available for a Linode NodeBalancer (as mentioned in my first paragraph).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My question is, are KeepAlives already implemented in socket.io by
>   default?

Yes, a `ping` packet (a very small webSocket packet) is sent every so often as a heartbeat to "test" the connection and make sure it is still functional and to keep it alive.  A `pong` packet is returned from the `ping` request so the sender knows whether the `ping` got through or not.

This ping aspect of socket.io is very poorly documented, but by examining the [source code of engine.io](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/2c0ae2972b20f6e843dffea17d11262adee3a381/lib/socket.js) which socket.io uses, there is both a `pingTimeout` (how long to wait for a `pong` response and a `pingInterval` (how often to send a `ping`).

Comment: @kojow7 - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. And you can set options.

```html
var myApp = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(myApp);

var io = require('socket.io')(http, {'pingTimeout': 7000, 'pingInterval': 3000});
```

Comment: Where did you get that info? `pingTimeout` `pingInterval` etc? Is there any reference in their documentation?

Comment: @RazBuchnik sure, take a look
https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#pingtimeout

Comment: Question: The higher the numbers, the better the connection, which means it can keep the connections for longer.?